# Realm's Swift module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I just updated to XCode 9.1 and when trying to compile my project which was running before under XCode 9.0.1 and Realm 3.0.0, I get the error message 'Module compiled with Swift 4.0 cannot be imported in Swift 4.0.2' at the Realm import in my code

```
import RealmSwift
```

I have:
- updated to Realm 3.0.1
- Reinstalled the Framework into my project
- Cleaned the project with the function in XCode

In the Realm 3.0.1 package there is no Swift-4.0.2 folder, only Swift-4.0.

Should Realm 3.0.1 be compatible to Xcode 9.1? If so, what can I do to make it work? If not, is a new version being created?

Thanks for help.

Regards
Christian

Comment: I had the same issue with Alamofire. I just recompiled with Carthage (copy framework files) and I'm up and running again

Comment: Thanks. This helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, but with the module SocketIO. Recompiling the framework with Carthage worked for me. After that I also had to clean the build folder.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me as well. I hadn't used Carthage before but now I have solved this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.0.2 is not ABI compatible with Swift 4.0, so the binaries you use as dependencies need to be recompiled.

Two approaches are reasonable here:

1. Use **Carthage** that will rebuild the Realm for you. (or build the Realm from source youself)
2. If you are not using Carthage or you don't wish to building Realm from source yourself, just install external [Swift 4.0 Toolchain](https://swift.org/builds/swift-4.0-release/xcode/swift-4.0-RELEASE/swift-4.0-RELEASE-osx.pkg) and select it within Xcode -> Preferences -> Components -> Toolchains so you are back with Xcode 9.0 swift toolchain until Realm will release their update.

Comment: It's tedious that a patch release of Swift would break ABI compatibility.